# "Multi" scope guard using template argument deducing feature

Tags: c++, scope, c++17

Using modern *C++* feature [*template argument deduction for class templates*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) and [*folding expressions*](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4295.html) it is possible to implement "multi" scope guard utility, which have right order of functor calls:

```
#include <utility>

template< std::size_t I, typename F >
struct wrapper { F f; };

template< std::size_t I, typename F >
constexpr
F &
get(wrapper< I, F > * sg) noexcept
{
    return sg->f;
}

template< typename index_sequence, typename ...F >
struct scope_guard_base;
    
template < std::size_t ...I, typename ...F >
struct scope_guard_base< std::index_sequence< I... >, F... >
    : wrapper< I, F >...
{
    using base = scope_guard_base;
    scope_guard_base(F &... f) : wrapper< I, F >{std::forward< F >(f)}... { ; }
    ~scope_guard_base() { (get< (sizeof...(I) - 1 - I) >(this)(), ...); }
};

template< typename ...F >
struct scope_guard
    : scope_guard_base< std::index_sequence_for< F... >, F... >
{
    scope_guard(F &&... f) : scope_guard::base(f...) { ; }
};

#include <iostream>

template< std::size_t I >
struct F
{
    
    F() { std::cout << I << std::endl; }

    void operator () () const { std::cout << I << std::endl; }

};

int main()
{
    F< 0 > const f{};
    scope_guard _{f, F< 1 >{}, F< 2 >{}};
}
```

Output:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 2
>
> 1
>
> 0

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SQ3Y0CHJ8fdo2F8w).

Comment: This has a deadlock bug. If you do multi-mutex locking you need to pay special attention to the order of locking the mutexes (usually by the address) to avoid deadlock.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Can you get an explanation? Can't find information about RAII and multiple mutexes deadlock interference.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Curly brackets (list initialization) guarantees strict ordering, I sure. At every step.

Comment: one thread calls `scope_guard _{&mut1, &mut2};` another calls `scope_guard _{&mut2, &mut1};` this can result in deadlock when each thread gets just one mutex.

Comment: @ratchetfreak How it possible? It is defenitely different code. It is not the bug. It's looks like programmer's mistake.

Comment: But if you have 2 objects trying to lock both its own mutex and the other's then both will be doing `scope_guard _{&this->mut, &other->mut};` with the exact same deadlock.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Are you sure is it inherent problem of namely this approach?